# Nagios external commands getting processed intermittently

Tags: nagios

I have a script that runs every 10 mins that updates the Host Comments field in Nagios. There are about 600 hosts and I am seeing some issues. The script deletes the previous comments and adds new ones. The issue I am seeing is that the comments are getting deleted intermittently.

I am using Nagios 3.2.2

Here is the script -

```
FILE = open("/var/log/nagios/rw/nagios.cmd","w")
  NOW = int(time.time())
  HOSTS = ["host1", "host2",etc]

  for hosts in HOSTS:
                DEL_COMMENT = "["+str(NOW)+"] DEL_ALL_HOST_COMMENTS;"+hosts+"\n"
                FILE.write(DEL_COMMENT)
  FILE.close()
```

The Nagios log shows that the comment was read -

```
  [1402964971] EXTERNAL COMMAND: DEL_ALL_HOST_COMMENTS;host1
  [1402964971] EXTERNAL COMMAND: DEL_ALL_HOST_COMMENTS;host2
  [1402964971] EXTERNAL COMMAND: DEL_ALL_HOST_COMMENTS;host3
```

Edit: Comments are getting deleted intermittently means comments on some of the hosts don't get deleted even though nagios log shows that the command for that host was sent to the external commands file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your conclusion that they're "getting deleted intermittently"?

Comment: The comments on some of the hosts don't get deleted. The nagios log shows the above output for the hosts but the comments still exist in the host comment field on those hosts.

Comment: My guess is that you are running into some kind of race condition. I'd suggest inserting some kind of sleep between the writes to the external command file.

Comment: That's what I thought. So I issued a single external command against a single problematic host and couldn't delete the comment. I couldn't "Delete all comments" through the WebUI either. The only way I could delete comments on those hosts was using the comment_ids. I am using a combination of live query and python script to get grab the comment_ids and delete them.